# Laravel - show few posts on homepage, then link to rest

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to create simple blog in Laravel and I got stuck with this little detail. I have blog posts and want to show few on homepage and have link to the others paginated at route localhost/posts.

The problem is I don't know how to create a link to the paginated posts from homepage, so the pagination begins where last post from homepage ends.

edit: I want the user to be able click on route 'posts' and see all posts, even those from homepage

Example

```
localhost/  - has first 3 posts 
localhost/posts?page=2  - has the rest starting from 4th post
```

I've tried it like this, but with no avail.

**Route**

```
Route::get('posts?page={page}', ['as' => 'rest', 'uses' => 'Controller@getRest']);
```

**Controller** has this function

```
public function getRest($page) {
    Paginator::setCurrentPage($page);
    $posts = Post::paginate(3);

    return View::make('posts')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

I tried creating link in homepage **view** template like so:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('posts?page={page}', 2) }}">Show the rest of posts</a>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. The only problem is, when user clicks `page 2` link in home page, user will see 10 posts, starting after the 13th, not the 3rd post. While changing `->skip(3 + ($page - 1) * 10)` in `Controller::posts` to `->skip(3 + ($page - 2) * 10)` might seem to do the trick, the `page 1` link will fail.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', [ 'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'Controller@home' ]);
Route::get('posts', [ 'as' => 'posts', 'uses' => 'Controller@posts' ]);
```

**Controller**

```
class Controller extends BaseController {

    public function home()
    {
        $posts = Post::take(3)->get();
        $pagination = Paginator::make($posts->toArray(), Post::count(), 10);

        $pagination->setBaseUrl(route('posts'));

        return View::make('home', compact('posts', 'pagination'));
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        // Current page number (defaults to 1)
        $page = Input::get('page', 1);

        // Get 10 post according to page number, after the first 3
        $posts = Post::skip(3 + ($page - 1) * 10)->take(10)->get();

        // Create pagination
        $pagination = Paginator::make($posts->toArray(), Post::count(), 10);

        return View::make('posts', compact('posts', 'pagination'));
    }

}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

     {{ $post->title }}

@endforeach

{{ $pagination->links() }}
```

Comment: Paginator throws error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Pagination\Factory::make() must be of the type array` Also, I'm not sure it does what I want. I need to paginate only posts without three that are on homepage.

Comment: Try this
Paginator::make($posts->toArray(), Post::count(), 10);

Comment: I updated the code and wrote a note on top. @ChainList thanks for the heads up.

Comment: When I use `$posts = Post::take(3)->get();` and dd it's an array with attributes, but I got still the same error with the make() **edit:** I will try it with skip

Comment: I just tested my codes in my answer, and they work without any PHP errors, but as I mentioned in the answer, there's a problem.

Comment: You might, however, don't use `Pagination` class in home page, and provide a custom "Read more" text with link to `{{ route('posts') }}` without any page numbers. That would solve the unseen 10 posts from 4 to 13 problem.

Comment: Thanks Hakan, I solved it. Turns out, paginator picks up parameter from link and sets the right page on its own.

Comment: @Rion dd() is using the var_dump function, which is calling de __toString() magic method when displaying a class.
We are lucky, Laravel's Collection does implement array access interface and the __toString() method too. That's why dd() is displaying an Array intead of an object.
You can see here : http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html
that get method can return a Collection or Builder class, not an array.
Sorry for my bad english by the way !